# Which two functions, each with a degree of one, are orthogonal to one another?

Tags: polynomials, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials

Two polynomials $f$ and $g$ are orthogonal, when the dot-product $\langle f,g \rangle = 0$.

How can I describe all polynomials $f$ and $g$, each with a degree of $1$, that are orthogonal to each other?

I've found the example $f(x) = -3x + 1$ and $g(x) = x + 1$, but I cannot find a good generalization for $f$ and $g$.

I'd love to hear some ideas! :)

Comment: Try starting with $f(x) = ax+b$, $g(x) = cx + d$ and then working out $\langle f, g\rangle = 0$ to get conditions on $a,b,c,d$.